# What are some good resources for getting started with COBOL programming?

Tags: cobol

I'm thinking about learning COBOL. Where should I start?

Comment: Is there a Managed COBOL Compiler?

Comment: Just to note: Microfocus have a COBOL.Net which integrates COBOL with the .Net libraries.

Comment: Fujitsu also has a .NET COBOL compiler that does not have runtime licensing restrictions.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I started with this excellent [tutorial](http://www.csis.ul.ie/COBOL/).

There is an open-source COBOL compiler called [OpenCOBOL](http://www.opencobol.org/) which you could use to work through the exercises.

And a COBOL [Portal](http://www.cobolportal.com/index.asp?bhcp=1).

Answer (score 2):

I did Cobol during the Y2K time, Cobol was the easy part, the nightmare was JCL or Job Control Language to run your Cobol programs, what a disaster!

I really, really would like to know why you even are thinking of learning Cobol

Comment: I won't tell you why I am thinking of learning COBOL, but I will tell you I knew I would get some good answers by asking.

Comment: I can answer that for myself: I'm seriously looking into learning cobol because some really big companies are paying the best salaries to cobol programmers, the systems behind these companies won't change anytime soon and the demand for more cobol programmers is growing not shrinking... at least here im my area.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to the book "Structured COBOL Programming, Second Edition" by Shelly Cashman Foremam. I studied this book and it is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

IBM i5/OS Information Center link:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/systems/scope/i5os/index.jsp?topic=/rzahg/rzahgcobol.htm

I know very little about this language so I can't tell you how much of the language information is IBM-specific.

Answer (score 0):

There are also:

[http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-COBOL-Hours/dp/0672314533/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1234194482&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672314533) which says it comes with the free fujitsu compiler that is not available for download anymore as far as I know

and

[http://www.amazon.com/Sams-Teach-Yourself-COBOL-Days/dp/0672317885/ref=sr_1_4?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1234194482&sr=8-4](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672317885)

Also, the Murach books are supposed to be very good.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the easy [COBOL Tutorial](http://mainframeopenbook.com/Content/COBOL/Tutorial.html) and few [COBOL sample programs](http://mainframeopenbook.com/Content/COBOL/Samples.html)